# jquery on error load different src

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am loading video source into a video player.  If the file is not there it will return an error.  If there is an error I want to load a different video source.  It always tries to load the original source.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
    var ezSource = "http://refwatch-<?php echo $league;?>-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/<?php echo $needle3 . $fcount; ?>.mp4";
    ez.on('click', function(){
        $('#mp4').on('error', function() {
            var ezSource = "http://refwatch-<?php echo $league; ?>-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/<?php echo $needle4 . $fcount; ?>.mp4";
            $('#mp4').on('error', function() {
                $.gritter.add({
                    image:'https://www.myrefwatch.com/img/note-logo.png',
                    // heading of the notification
                    title: 'Sorry!',
                    // the text inside the notification
                    text: 'The video is not there or the video cannot be loaded.'
                });
            });
        });
        alert(ezSource);
        $('#mp4').attr('src', ezSource);
        $('#videoClip').load();
```

I really appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Can you please update the code with the rendered code after PHP? That way users can verify that the file you are attempting to swap with exists in first place or etc?

Comment: You don't need the rendered code.  The first ezsource variable is the file to open.  If that file is not found open the second ezsource variable.  but it is not working.  It never tries to open the second ezsource

Comment: You can change the ezsource to be any file local to your computer.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  I needed to load twice.

```
        var ez = $('#EZ');
        var ezSource = "http://refwatch-<?php echo $league; ?>-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/<?php echo $needle3; ?>" + idVid + ".mp4";
        ez.on('click', function(){
            $('#mp4').on('error', function() {
                var ezSource = "http://refwatch-<?php echo $league; ?>-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/<?php echo $needle4; ?>" + idVid + ".mp4";
                $('#mp4').on('error', function() {
                    $.gritter.add({
                        image:'https://www.myrefwatch.com/img/note-logo.png',
                        // heading of the notification
                        title: 'Sorry!',
                        // the text inside the notification
                        text: 'The video is not there or the video cannot be loaded.'
                    });
                });
                $('#mp4').attr('src', ezSource);
                $('#videoClip').load();
            });
            $('#mp4').attr('src', ezSource);
            $('#videoClip').load();

        });
```

thank you for your help.